# Ancestor queries using the new Google Cloud console UI

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

How can I specify an ancestor query using the new Google Cloud Storage UI?

[image: Google Cloud Storage Query UI]

The image above shows the field to specify the query. I'd like to query for a User that has a specific parent id.

How'd that be?

P.S. It'd be great if Google adds some sort of documentation to this UI.

Comment: Unfortunately its not possible to do anything relating to ancestors. The parent is hidden on the console, you will have to use code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try this using GQL syntax using this tab showed in the pictured attached.

Try something like this:

SELECT * YOUKIND WHERE **key** HAS ANCESTOR KEY(Person, 'Amy')

[Reference](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference) : https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference